# How serve "only responsive" content to mobile m. subdomain without redirect?

Tags: html, redirect, mobile, responsive-design

So now I have a www. site that redirects to different content m. site. But I'm updating my site to responsive content. I don't want to loose m. links in Google SERP.

So, how do I redirect my www. site to serve the responsive content on mobile m. subdomain?

It's all HTML site. I don't want to upload same content to both www. and m. domains each time I update site. Is there a way?  My new responsive site will just redirect users to mobile friendly www. site. I want it to go to m. subdomain. I heard there is a way to set something up on a server.

Comment: Nevermind. I just did a document root index for m. to go to www. Kind of like a multistore. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a small script in your index. Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 690) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Comment: Do you guys not read ny question in full ?   No. I don't have CMS. So no plugin. Also I don't want to upload seperated content on m. site.  I need to serve both sites from one www location since www is responsive now

Comment: What manages the redirect of the mobile site? You can simply redirect all traffic to that one DNS.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Plugins to redirect**

If you are running a Content Management System (such as WordPress or Joomla), there may be plugins already available that help with handling mobile visitors. The best way to find these plugins is to either search Google or to search the software's website.

**Javascript window.location Method**

Mobile phones typically have a small screen width, so you should redirect visitors to your mobile site if they have a screen width of less than or equal to 800 pixels. You place this code in the head section of your main website code. That way when your site is visited, the javascript will see the browser width and redirect to the appropriate site

You can use the following code to do this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

**.htaccess URL rewrite redirects Where JAVASCRIPT NOT WORKING**

You can use a .htaccess redirect to transfer visitors based upon the MIME types the browser supports. For example, if the user's browser accepts mime types that include WML (Wireless Markup Language), then most likely it is a mobile device.

The code below should be placed in your .htaccess file:

```js
RewriteEngine On
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just solved it. I just changed document root link for m. to go to www. Kind of like a multistore.
I sent server root document link for "m.aaa.com" to go to "public_html/www.aaa.com" instead of  "public_html/m.aaa.com".

Works like a charm.